# c# - The given ColumnName 'xxxxxxx' does not match up with any column in data source

Tags: sqlbulkcopy

In my code has an issue but I can't see what issue in this. Column names are same word by word and it is working, If I use 1 column in csv file but when I try out more then 2-3 column fields it is giving the error below. I have checked read lots of article so I can't fix the error. What can be happen with is this lines. DB already was created with similar fields.

```
private void DBaktar()
    {


        string SQLServerConnectionString = "Server =.\\SQLEXPRESS; Database = Qiti; User Id = sa; Password = 7731231xx!!;";
        string CSVpath = @"D:\FTP\"; // CSV file Path
        string CSVFileConnectionString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};;Extended Properties=\"text;HDR=Yes;FMT=Delimited\";", CSVpath);

        var AllFiles = new DirectoryInfo(CSVpath).GetFiles("*.CSV");
        string File_Name = string.Empty;

        foreach (var file in AllFiles)
        {
            try
            {


                DataTable dt = new DataTable();

                using (OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(CSVFileConnectionString))
                {
                    con.Open();
                    var csvQuery = string.Format("select * from [{0}]", file.Name);
                    using (OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(csvQuery, con))
                    {
                        da.Fill(dt);
                    }
                }

                using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(SQLServerConnectionString))
                {
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("LKod", "LKod");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("info", "info");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Codex", "Codex");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("LthNo", "LthNo");
                    bulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Datein", "Datein");


                    bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "U_Tik";
                    bulkCopy.BatchSize = 0;
                    bulkCopy.EnableStreaming = true;

                    bulkCopy.WriteToServer(dt);
                    bulkCopy.Close();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            }

        }
```

### Error exception;

> The given ColumnName 'LKod' does not match up with any column in data
>   source.

### ex.StackTrace;

> at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteRowSourceToServerCommon(Int32
>   columnCount)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteRowSourceToServerAsync(Int32
>   columnCount, CancellationToken ctoken)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(DataTable table,
>   DataRowState rowState)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(DataTable table)

Answer (score 0):

Some information can be found here: https://sqlbulkcopy-tutorial.net/columnmapping-does-not-match

### Cause

- You didn't provide any ColumnMappings, and there is more column in the source than in the destination.
- You provided an invalid column name for the source.
- You provided an invalid column name for the destination.

### Solution

- ENSURE to provide a ColumnMappings
- ENSURE all values for source column name are valid and case sensitive.
- ENSURE all values for destination column name are valid and case sensitive.
- MAKE the source case insensitive

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution and working 100% true.. The link below, I hope become a path who need that.

https://johnnycode.com/2013/08/19/using-c-sharp-sqlbulkcopy-to-import-csv-data-sql-server/